# If you add type A blood to type B blood, is there a visible reaction?

Tags: hematology, blood-group

I read that [the original discovery of blood types was because they combined random blood samples togethers and noticed a reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABO_blood_group_system#History). I was wondering if this was a visible reaction? Or is anti-A or anti-B serum explicitly required?

Comment: Blood contains serum too.